# How do you load Machinist's blueprints when using Spork?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, spork

How do you load Machinist's blueprints when using Spork?

Gems:

- mongoid (2.0.0.rc.6)
- capybara (0.4.1.1)
- steak (1.1.0)
- spork (0.9.0.rc2)
- rspec (2.4.0)
- machinist (2.0.0.beta2)

I get this error in every acceptance test:

```
Machinist::NoBlueprintError:
   No master blueprint defined for class School
```

All test fail, because it doesn't find any blueprint. I some of these errors on V2(I still get a couple of No master blueprint..), but I get another error too:

```
Professor Create a new professor
 Failure/Error: click_link("Profesores")
 RangeError:
   0x000000821461e4 is recycled object
```

I got config.cache_classes = false  in test environment for this one.

Both spec_helper versions:

https://gist.github.com/801814

Comment: I managed to load de blueprints. Edited the Gist. But I get a different error,RangeError: 0x000000821461e4 is recycled object. Check the edit.

Comment: That error is related to your blueprint - what version of Machinist are you using, and what does your blueprints file look like?

Comment: @pat: I added the blueprints.rb file to the gist. https://gist.github.com/801814   and is machinist (2.0.0.beta2)

Comment: @pat: Also, everything worked before using Spork. What does it mean RangeError:
   0x000000821461e4 is recycled object ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to rule out the obvious have you included something like this in your application.rb file:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.fixture_replacement :machinist      
end
```

Also have you set up your blueprints files in:

```
features/support/blueprints.rb for cucumber   
spec/support/blueprints.rb for rspec
```

and made sure you've included:

```
require 'machinist/active_record'
```

in the top of your blueprints.

Also just on another note for when you get it up and running. Machinist caches a lot of objects to make it run faster, but it may occasionally trip you up when constantly trying to clear out the database. If you run into problems you can turn off Machinists caching by adding this to your config/environments/test.rb file:

```
Machinist.configure do |config|
  config.cache_objects = false
end
```

Comment: Yeah, everything worked before using spork. I will try to configure it again but going using it from the start, so I see where it fails exactly.

Comment: Can you share the spec_helper of you project? That could really help me when I get to the task.

Comment: The spec_helper is on the article I linked to. Haven't been running RSpec tests with machinist just yet.. Only Cucumber so far. Gimme 10 mins, I'll see if I can get em running..

Comment: Yeah runs through fine using the machinist blueprints. You don't need to make any more changes to the spec_helper in the article for it to work.